# Gazebo didn’t launch with urdf

Tags: gazebo, urdf, spawn, launch-file, gazebo-worlds

Running on vm, I created a simple launch file to launch Gazebo with the robot urdf, an error was shown.

launch file Content:

```
<launch>
       <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch"/>
       <node name="spawn_model" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" output="screen" args="-urdf -model turtlebot -param robot_description">
           <param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find multi_robot)/src/turtlebot.urdf"/>
       </node>
</launch>
```

urdf

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <robot name="turtlebot">
      <link name="base_link">
            <visual>
               <geometry><box size="0.5 0.5 0.5"/></geometry>
            </visual>
      </link>
   </robot>
```

**Attempted to solve the issue:**

- checked directory, path
- remove build and devel, source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash, ~/.bashrc
  and ws setup.bash, redo catkin_make
- checked gazebo_msgs, gazebo_ros to have all the packages, script,
  correct node name, dependencies
- rosdep update, sudo apt update, updated noetic, sudo rosdep
  fix-permissions
- reinstalled Gazebo

**Persisted issue:**
Gazebo was unable to load urdf, robot model, world. But the insert function can manually add them.

Error message:

```
[ INFO] [1692378515.995051190]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin. 
[spawn_model-4] process has died /home/user/catkin_ws/devel/lib/gazebo_ros/spawn_model -urdf -model turtlebot -param robot_description __name:=spawn_model __log:=/home/user/.ros/log/dd4d5694-3de9-11ee-bbc9-ededcfbcc7ca/spawn_model-4.log]. log file: /home/user/.ros/log/dd4d5694-3de9-11ee-bbc9-ededcfbcc7ca/spawn_model-4*.log 
[ INFO] [1692378516.697968553]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
[ INFO] [1692378516.735021098, 0.019000000]: Physics dynamic reconfigure ready.
```

spawn_mode-4.log

```
[rospy.client][INFO] 2023-08-18 17:08:35,621: init_node, name[/spawn_model], pid[64745] [xmlrpc]
[INFO] 2023-08-18 17:08:35,621: XML-RPC server binding to 0.0.0.0:0 [xmlrpc]
[INFO] 2023-08-18 17:08:35,622: Started XML-RPC server [http://a-vm:35987/] [rospy.init][INFO] 2023-08-18 17:08:35,622: ROS Slave URI: [http://a-vm:35987/] [rospy.impl.masterslave][INFO] 2023-08-18 17:08:35,622: _ready: hhttp://a-vm:35987/ [rospy.registration]
[INFO] 2023-08-18 17:08:35,623: Registering with master node http://localhost:11311 [xmlrpc][INFO] 2023-08-18 17:08:35,623: xml rpc node: starting XML-RPC server [rospy.init]
[INFO] 2023-08-18 17:08:35,723: registered with master [rospy.rosout]
[INFO] 2023-08-18 17:08:35,723: initializing /rosout core topic [rospy.rosout]
[INFO] 2023-08-18 17:08:35,729: connected to core topic /rosout [rospy.simtime]
[INFO] 2023-08-18 17:08:35,730: initializing /clock core topic [rospy.simtime]
[INFO] 2023-08-18 17:08:35,732: connected to core topic /clock [rosout]
[INFO] 2023-08-18 17:08:35,734: Loading model XML from ros parameter robot_description [rospy.core][INFO] 2023-08-18 17:08:35,861: signal_shutdown [atexit] [rospy.impl.masterslave]
[INFO] 2023-08-18 17:08:35,864: atexit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the launch file to have the parameter before and outside of `<node>`

```
<launch>
       <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch"/>
       <param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find multi_robot)/src/turtlebot.urdf"/>
       <node name="spawn_model" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" output="screen" args="-urdf -model turtlebot -param robot_description">
       </node>
</launch>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Robotics StackExchange. For you answer to be more useful, please try to pinpoint in words what exactly did you change. It is hard to spot the difference. If you can, please also reformat the launch file in the question so that it is apparent that the `<param>` tag was put inside the `<node>` tag (it is not indented, so it is hard to figure it out).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).